# Editing and Publishing Python Packages While Maintaining Version Control

Tags: python, git, package

I am building and publishing my first package.

I have the build/publish process down.  But my question is how I edit, publish, and install changes I make to the package going forward.

Another post attempts to address but it is dated and unclear to me:

[Python: how to edit an installed package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075397/python-how-to-edit-an-installed-package)

It seems the suggested way to go about this is per the other question is to fork the package and publish.  But I'm not clear how to update and publish afterward while maintaining version control?    Could someone address how to publish / edit / push to git explicitly?

Also, when the package is updated, how do we update the packages that have been distributed?  Do we just tell people that we've made changes and they re-install?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How/where to publish Python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031411/how-where-to-publish-python-package)

Comment: No.  The question is about editing packages, updating them, and maintaining version control.